# What is the idiom for " If it is something impossible to believe it"

Tags: idioms, popular-refrains

Often, when something really odd is said,or if something impossible to believe is said to have happened, Turks say:" Yeah, if you eat it".

I wonder what is   the corresponding idiom in English? If I use the the above term, is it understood by natives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when something really odd is said, or if something impossible to believe is said to have happened

It's not entirely clear if you mean that the thing is a made-up story or that it has *actually* occurred despite assumptions to the contrary.

For the former:

[**"Pull the other one!"**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pull-the-other-leg-one-it-s-got-bells-on)  (Also, "Pull the other leg," and sometimes ending in "it's got bells on.")

> [Cambridge]
>
> used when you do not believe what someone has just said:
>
> *Helen, mountain climbing? Pull the other one - she can't even climb a ladder without feeling sick!*

For the latter:

[**"Truth is stranger than fiction."**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/truth-is-stranger-than-fiction)

> [Cambridge]
>
> said when you want to emphasize that real events or things are sometimes stranger than imaginary ones
>
> *I know it sounds unbelievable, but truth is sometimes stranger than fiction.*

Comment: I think that there is a closer one which is very similar to it. "Buy something".

Answer (score 2):

> [take (something) with a pinch of salt](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+with+a+grain+of+salt) To consider or evaluate
>   something, such as a statement, while keeping in mind that it may not
>   be completely true or accurate, typically due to the unreliability of
>   the source.
>
> *I heard that you can get a free movie ticket if you wear red, but Kevin told me that, so I'm going to take it with a pinch of salt.*
>
> *Take whatever that paper publishes with a pinch of salt—it's really
>   a tabloid.*

Idioms.thefreedictionar.com

Answer (score 1):

Here's something structurally similar, though it slants towards accepting empirical evidence over theoretical suspicion.

> **the proof of the pudding is in the eating**
>   The real value of something can be judged only from practical experience or results and not from appearance or theory.
>   ‘‘What he said today I think reduces the chances of us having to move into a confrontational position but the proof of the pudding is in the eating,’ he said.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/the_proof_of_the_pudding_is_in_the_eating)